# Error NETSDK1004: Assets file 'project.assets.json' not found

Tags: c#, .net-5

I am trying to publish my .NET 5 application, when publishing with Target runtime = Portable publish succeeds, when changing target runtime to win-x64 for example the publish fails.

Before failing i get this error in output which is probably related.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\NuGet\NuGet.targets(131,5): Error : Invalid framework identifier ''.
```

I have noticed that the **'project.assets.json'** is generated in **'obj\project.assets.json'** dir but it looks like the build process actually expect it to be in **'obj\publish\win-x64\project.assets.json'** and its not present there. Manually copying the file makes everything work but such approach would be very tedious.

Is there any project configuration I need to look into ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem was caused by some dependent project libraries having AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath set to false.